# Get total time and create an average based on timestamps

Tags: math, time, coldfusion

**Background:** I want to use coldfusion to find the total time a process takes by taking two timestamps and then adding all of the total times to create an average.

Question: What is the best way to take two timestamps and find out the difference in time by minutes.

**Example:**

```
Time Stamp #1:  2015-05-08 15:44:00.000
Time Stamp #2:  2015-05-11 08:52:00.000
```

**So the time between the above timestamps would be:**
2 Days 6 hours 52 mins  =  3,292 minutes

I want to run this conversion on a handful of timestamp's and take the total minutes and divide to get an average.

To add more information to my question. 1. Yes the values are coming from a DB MSSQL. 2. I am actually going to be using the individual time differences and showing and overall average. So in my for loop each line will have a value like 3,292 (converted to mins or hours or days) and at the end of the for loop I want to show an average of all the lines shown on the page. Let me know if I need to add any other information.

Comment: This sounds like data that should be stored in a DB

Comment: What's the part causing you difficulty?

Comment: This could be approached several ways, but it depends on information you have not provided. 1. What is the source of the two timestamps - a database table? If so, what is your DBMS? 2. What is the overall goal - to generate a single average overall OR retrieve all timestamps *plus* generate an overall average? To generate a single average use SQL functions. Those vary by DBMS, so without knowing more my suggestion would be to look at your database's version of DateDiff and AVG (average) functions.

Comment: Leigh I have added more information to my question based on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your query is sorted properly, something like this should work.

```
totalMinutes = 0;
for (i = 2; i <= yourQuery.recordcount; i++)
totalMinutes += 
    DateDiff('n'
    , yourQuery.timestampField[i-1]
    ,yourQuery.timestampField[i]);

avgMinutes = totalMinutes / (yourQuery.recordcount -1);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity why set "i" to 22?

Comment: The technical term for that is, "mistake".

Comment: haha. Thanks. Your example has been very help to understand how to use DateDiff. +1 checked.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`dateDiff()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DateDiff) function

```
diffInMinutes = dateDiff('n', date1, date2);
```

Comment: Yes, some sort of DateDiff function will be part of the solution. Though not necessarily CF's version of that function. If the values are stored in a database - and the goal is generate a *single* total - then it is more efficient to use database functions.  However, the OP is not very clear about the source of the values - or what they have tried - so it is hard to say...

Comment: Leigh I apologize about not being clear. You are correct the values are coming from a MSSQL database. Is it possible to do this type of calculation in the query? Would it be more efficient that way vs getting the values from the DB and doing the calc's in my for loop?

Comment: @Denoteone - It depends. My question was whether you even need a loop at all. The answer depends on your goal.  If all you need is a single total, then pulling a bunch of records and looping in CF does not make sense. You can calculate the total more efficiently in a single SQL query and return a single value. If however, you actually needed to display those records (PLUS a total) then looping makes more sense, because you are actually using the data retrieved from the database. Make sense?

Comment: *If all you need is a single total* In other words, why pull a 1000 records of data from the database, when all you really need is a single number (which can be done in SQL)?